# Created Partition but not showing up on install wizard - dual booting ubuntu 13.10 on WIndows 8

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-8

I know there are dozens of similar questions and sorry for asking another one, but I can't find an answer that tells me about my problem.

I created a 10gb partition in windows 8 which is now unallocated space. I restarted into try ubuntu and wanted to install it. When I came to the installation type option it showed me two options: Erase disk and install ubuntu or something else.

I chose something else, but when I did it only showed me my C drive as 500gb free space. The 10gb which I unallocated was not shown there.

I want to know if I continue with partitioning my C drive (which has windows 8 on it), will that erase anything on that drive? What will it do, and why is the installation not showing the 10gb that I've unallocated? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there's no such thing as a "partition... which is... unallocated space." A partition is, *by definition*, allocated space. If you deleted or shrank a partition, the result is unallocated space. Although I believe I understand your meaning in this case, miscommunication on this score can lead to a lot of wasted effort as two parties communicate at cross purposes.

Second, although it's OK to shrink partitions in Windows in preparation for installing Linux, you should *never* create a partition using the Windows tools with the intention of using it in Linux. Doing so may work if you're lucky, but if you're not lucky, Windows will implement its proprietary [Logical Disk Manager (LDM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager) system, and you'll have to jump through hoops to undo this change before you can install Linux. I don't believe this accounts for your problem, but it bears mentioning.

My suspicion is that you're using an older Master Boot Record (MBR) partitioning scheme and have run into a partition table difficulty. There are several things that can cause this type of problem. Many of them can be fixed with my [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) program. See its documentation, and [this page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/missing-parts/index.html) I've written on the topic. If you still have problems, post back with more detail, such as the output of the following commands, typed in a Linux terminal from an emergency disc:

```
fdisk -l /dev/sda
parted /dev/sda print
gdisk -l /dev/sda
```

If you use Ubuntu, precede each of those commands by `sudo`; with other emergency discs or distributions, be sure you log in as `root`. (Logging in as `root` is standard with most Linux emergency discs.) If you use Ubuntu, you'll probably have to install `gdisk` by typing `sudo apt-get install gdisk`, too. Edit your original question to include the output of these commands.